# What Are the Properties of 43' Vertical Monopoles Used as Multiband Radiators?

Tags: vertical-antenna

43' vertical monopoles sometimes are used with an auto-tuner at their input as radiators in the ham bands from 40m through 10m, but are any performance compromises required to do that?

Answer (score 3):

While using a 43' vertical monopole as a Z-matched radiator on the upper ham bands through 10 meters can make the transmitter happy, it has considerably less gain/usefulness on 10 meters than a typical Ground Plane antenna installation does for the greatest range, single-hop DX contacts from the important elevation sector below about 25 degrees (see following graphic):

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for this analysis that, as you did, can only be performed properly with NEC-4. How much does the 43-ft monopole's performance improve if insulated radials are simply laid on the ground, rather than being buried?

Comment: Negligible change, based on previous studies I did using NEC4.2 to compare insulated vs.uninsulated radials (other things the same),

Comment: @BrianK1LI why would NEC-2 have been insufficient for Richard's analysis?

Comment: @rclocher3  NEC-2 doesn't model buried conductors.